# MODIS images set CRS and reproject

Tags: qgis, python, modis

I am developing a plugin which reads MODIS images, and I know that MODIS images are in sinusoidal projection and I need to set that CRS and project the image to WGS84 (epsg 4326) in python. I search and find QgsRasterProjector class but I don't understand how to use this class. Is there another way?

I also tried the processing commands but there isn't Assign Projection command in processing, just the warp.

Comment: I can't help you on the plugin, but note that MODIS SWATH  (opposite to other MODIS images) are not sinusoidal.

Comment: you can use gdal_translate to overwrite the projection : gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs" infile outfile or directly project with gdalwarp by specifying s_srs and t_srs

Comment: gdal_translate can be used in plugin implementation?

Comment: You can see the following post. [Here.][1] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345691/using-python-gdal-to-reproject-an-hdf